# Type Error while using groupby, First function in Python, Ipython Notebook, Azure ML

Tags: python, python-2.7, group-by, transform, typeerror

I have a Dataset, where I create a new column using certain conditions. Then the values in that column are grouped based on the column "Thermostat".

I'm facing the below error, when executed in Jupyter or Azure ML. But the same is successfully executed in Spyder. Please let me know, how to go about it.

Code:

```
df['Last_Act_User'] = df.groupby(df['thermostat'].ne(df['thermostat'].shift()).cumsum())['Last_Act_User'].transform('first')
```

Error:

```
  File ".\Script Bundle\co.py", line 141, in pipeline_1
df['Last_Act_User'] = df.groupby(df['thermostat'].ne(df['thermostat'].shift()).cumsum())['Last_Act_User'].transform('first')

  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2210, in transform
res = wrapper(group)

  File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2203, in <lambda>
wrapper = lambda x: getattr(x, func)(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: first() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: run `pd.__version__` in all environments and add the result to your post

Comment: In Azure ML:
Microsoft Drawbridge Console Host [Version 1.0.2108.0]

Running with Python 2.7.7 |Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jun 11 2014, 10:40:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]




        In Spyder :
        0.18.1